# “I was sick" in Spanish

Tags: gramática

I know it will take **estar** and in the present tense it’s easy to just say, “**Estoy enfermo.**” But how do I say it in the past tense? Which one of the below would be correct?

**estuve enfermo.**

**estaba enfermo.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

both are valid sentences

- estuve enfermo

would be heard as polite excuse, ie. (At the office, explaining to colleagues about your sick leave), Estuve enfermo la semana pasada {I was sick the last week}

- estaba enfermo

something that you would say to friends, ie (with friends and family), estaba enfermo y ya estoy bien {I was sick, now I'm great}

Comment: Would it be fair to assume that “estuve enfermo” is more like “I fell sick” whereas “estaba enfermo” describes the state of being sick, i.e., “I was sick.”?

Comment: yes, it feels better that way, still both describe that in the past there was sickness

Comment: To my mind 'estaba enfermo' also could indicate a long-term illness that, perhaps, you had as a child.  Using 'estuve' indicates a short-term temporary sickness such as a cold.

Answer (score 4):

Anytime that time is declared in the statement, or question, preterite is to be used.  Otherwise, you will use the imperfect.

Examples:

**Preterito**

`Ayer, estuve enfermo`

This sentences communicates completely that

> You became sick yesterday but you are not sick today...

`Ayer, estuve enfermo mientras comía la cena anoche`

By adding a complementary action or clause (or whatever the linguistic term is for it) that uses the imperfect you communicate that:

> You got sick while eating dinner last night, but you are not sick now

`Ayer, estuve enfermo mientras comí la cena anoche`

Just for education's sake, if you make both of them preterite, then you communicate

> You got sick as soon as you ate dinner last night

*You can add `me` in front of `comí` and change it to*

> You got sick as soon as you at all of the dinner last night

**Imperfecto**

`Ayer, estaba enfermo`

This sentences communicates that

> you were sick yesterday and you may or may not still be sick today

When you use this form, the reader expects more to the sentence.  i.e,

> you were sick when you were cooking dinner,
>
> you were sick while listening to the speech,
>
> you were sick because you ate bad food.
>
> you were sick, and it was a Thursday, and your uncle Joe had called asking for money again.

And so on, and so on, and so on ...

Answer (score 3):

Depending on what you want to say, but I would say that `estuve enfermo` is the correct answer.

`Estaba enfermo` is `Pretérito imperfecto`. That means that we don't know if the action has end.

> Estaba enfermo cuando llamaron a la puerta.

After knoking the door you still felt sick and we do not know when you felt OK.

`Estuve enfermo` is `Pretérito perfecto simple`. We know this action ended in some point in the past.

> Ayer estuve enfermo, por eso no fui al cine.

Yesterday you felt sick and you didn't go to the cinema. Now you feel OK.

[Conjugación](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/apendices/apendice1.html#n34) del verbo `Estar`

Answer (score -1):

I was sick = estaba enfermo... estuve enfermo... los dos están correctos